# Second Date show me as 1st date in Result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I'm trying to do is here in sheet 1 in "Overtime date column" must match with sheet 2 "Date Column" Thanks

I tired this formula
"=+IFERROR(INDEX('OverTime DataBase'!C:C,MATCH('Fatigue Data'!A59,'OverTime DataBase'!A:A,0)),"")"

but its showing me onlly 1st result like you can see in Sample booksheek which  attached please download and see

https://mega.nz/#!tFhjAZrY!4JMl7nBk5j59rZr8vT9Z1jHKOHkA3rz5XgFfKtGgneE

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please read Help for how to ask a good question; and how to provide an example.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH gives you the first occurrence found in the range you have defined. Therefore if your search keys are not unique, you will always get the first value in the list and reference value. You should find a way to have a unique search key to link the two sheets, or modify the range of search accordingly to ensure that first occurrence is what you are looking for.